# how to update the list of options in react select or react-select.async

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to update the list of options on an event triggered elsewhere. i have saved the options in the state and when i have the updated list i setState which triggers the render but the select box does not show the updated list

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderSelectField = this.renderSelectField.bind(this);
        this.renderTextField = this.renderTextField.bind(this);
        this.updateCommsMatrix = this.updateCommsMatrix.bind(this);
        this.renderSelect2Field = this.renderSelect2Field.bind(this);
        this.clearValue = this.clearValue.bind(this);
        this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
        this.meta = {
            title: 'Request Exemption',
            description: 'This section allows you to request an exemption'
        };
        this.runOnce = false;
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            searchable: true,
            selectValue: 0,
            clearable: true,
            rtl: false,
            options: [
                { value: 0, label: 'All'}
                ]
        };
        this.exemptionType = {};
        this.markets = {};
        this.serviceDomain = {};
        this.servicesList = {};
        this.matrices = {};
    }
```

this section grabs the updated options to set in the select

```
    updateCommsMatrix(service_id){      

        if(service_id > 0){
            let self = this;
            this.props.fetchCommsmatricesByService(service_id)
            .then( response => {
                let data = response.payload.data.body.recordset.record;
                console.log(data);
                let options = self.populateOptionsObject(data, 'id', 'filename');
                options.unshift({ value: 0, label: 'All'});
                return options;
            })
            .then( options => this.setState({options:options}));
        }else{
            //select.append(<option value="0" key="0">All</option>);
        }
    }

    populateOptionsObject(options, key, value) {
        return options.map((option, index) => (
                {value : option[key], label: option[value] }
        ));
    }
```

below is the part that renders the form

```
    populateOptions(options, key, value) {
        return options.map((option, index) => (
            <option key={option.id} value={option[key]}>
                {option[value]}
            </option>
        ));
    }

    clearValue (e) {
        this.select.setInputValue('');
    }

    updateValue (newValue) {
        this.setState({
            selectValue: newValue,
        });
    }

    renderSelect2Field(field){
        let id = "select_" + field.input.name;
        let options = this.state.options;
        return(
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label col-sm-2">{field.label}</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                        <Select
                            id={id}
                            //className="col-sm-6"
                            ref={(ref) => { this.select = ref; }}
                            onBlurResetsInput={false}
                            onSelectResetsInput={false}
                            autoFocus
                            options={options} //on load this has 1 value (value=0, display text =All)
                            simpleValue
                            clearable={this.state.clearable}
                            name={field.input.name}
                            //disabled={this.state.disabled}
                            value={this.state.selectValue}
                            onChange={this.updateValue}
                            rtl={this.state.rtl}
                            searchable={this.state.searchable}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this);
        if (!this.runOnce && this.props.isReady) {
            this.runOnce = true;
            this.initData();
        }
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
        let form = 'Loading...';
        if (this.state.loaded) {
            return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form-horizontal">
                        <Field
                            label="Comms Matrix"
                            loadFrom="matrices"
                            name="comms_matrix_id"
                            component={this.renderSelect2Field}
                            type="select"
                        />
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="btn btn-vodafone hidden-print"
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return <div className="container-fluid">{form}</div>;
    }
}
```

I can load the select box on init load with a single option. i want to add/change the options list using `updateCommsMatrix`, you can see i am setting the state which is used in the select.

I have also tried `Async` option but wit this i cannot seem to get the display to show selected value and when i click on the drop down list it does not show the new list until i hit `spacebar`. With this method i am storing the `object` in `this.state.selectValue` I have taken this example from [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/examples/src/components/Contributors.js)

**ASYNC**

```
   <Async 
                            name={field.input.name}
                            multi={false} 
                            value={this.state.selectValue} 
                            onChange={this.updateValue} 
                            valueKey="value" 
                            labelKey="label" 
                            loadOptions={this.getCommsmatrices} 
                            onValueClick={this.gotoCommsmatrix}
                            cache={false}
                            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                        />



 getCommsmatrices (input, callback) {
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        let options = this.state.options.filter(i => {
            return i.label.toLowerCase().includes(input) == true;
            //return i.label.toLowerCase().substr(0, input.length) === input;
        });

        let data = {
            options: options,//.slice(0, MAX_CONTRIBUTORS),
            complete: true //options.length <= MAX_CONTRIBUTORS,
        };

        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, data);
        }, ASYNC_DELAY);
    }

    gotoCommsmatrix (value, event) {
        if(value.value > 0){
            window.open(window.top.protocol + '://' + window.top.hostname + '/api/user/commsmatrix/id/'+value.value+'/format/xml');
        }
    }
```

It seems to me when i select a value the input being passed into `loadOptions` is blank

Comment: theres too much going on here narrow it down if you can, show what you use to make the update, and then show the specific place where you call that function.

Comment: removed unnecessary code

Comment: I have the same problem. I see suggested hacks here but haven't gotten them to work: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1581#issuecomment-408625770 and https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1879#issuecomment-316871520